# Prove that $V = \ker T \oplus \text{Im}T$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T:V\to V$ such that $f_T = \sum_{i=0}^n c_ix^i$ and $c_1 = c_n = 1, c_0 = 0$.
Prove that $V = \ker T \oplus \text{Im}T$.

My thoughts so far:

- For some basis $B$, we have $[T]_B = A$. We know that $0=c_0 = (-1)^n\det A$. Therefore, $\det A = 0$ which implies $A$ isn't invertible and it's column are linearly independent.
- $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

Comment: Is $f_T(x)$ the characteristic polynomial of $T$?

Comment: @RobertLewis, yes.

Comment: Do you know what field your space is over? If it's over $\mathbb{Q}$, we have that $\frac{f_T(x)}{x}$ is a monic polynomial with constant term 1, so the rational roots test would say either $\pm 1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ or $\frac{f_T(x)}{x}$ is irreducible...

Comment: @walkar isn't it already monic because $c_1=c_n=1$?

Comment: @mathers101 I was commenting on the monic nature of $\frac{f_T(x)}{x}$ rather than just $f_T(x)$.

Comment: @walkar I'm not sure how I screwed that up, my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will directly prove that $V$ is the sum of $\ker T$ and $\text{im}T$. Since the characteristic polynomial is given, I will use Caley-Hamilton to proceed while using $c_1=1$, $c_0=0$.

Let $x$ in $V$. Then $f_T(T)x=0$ by Caley-Hamilton, hence
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n c_i T^ix = 0,
$$
or equivalently
$$
T\left(\sum_{i=1}^n c_i T^{i-1} x\right)=T\left(x+\sum_{i=2}^n c_i T^{i-1} x\right)=0,
$$
which helps us to identify an element in the null space of $T$ associated to the given $x$.
Now writing
$$
x = \underbrace{x+\sum_{i=2}^n c_i T^{i-1}x}_{\in \ker T} - \underbrace{\sum_{i=2}^n c_i T^{i-1}x}_{\in \text{im} T}
$$
shows that $\ker T + \text{im} T = V$. 
By the rank–nullity theorem, 
$$
\dim \ker T + \dim\text{im} T  = \dim V = \dim(\ker T + \text{im} T) = \dim \ker T + \dim\text{im} T + \dim(\ker T \cap \text{im} T),
$$
which implies that $\ker T \cap \text{im} T=\{0\}$, and the sum is direct.

---

The proof that the sum is direct can also be done with Caley-Hamilton. Take $y\in \ker T \cap \text{im} T$. Then there is $x\in V$ such that $Tx=y$ and $T^2x=0$. The latter implies $T^ix=0$ for all $i\ge 2$. Then by Cayley-Hamilton
$$
0=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i T^ix = T x .
$$
Hence $Tx=0$, $y=0$, and  $\ker T \cap \text{im} T=\{0\}$.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since $c_0=0$
$$f_T = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n c_ix^i=x\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} c_{i+1}x^i=xg(x)$$

Since $c_1=1$, $x$ and $g(x)$ are coprime. The minimum polynomial $m_T$ must contain all factors that are divided by $f_T$ and so, $m_T=xh(x)$, where $h|g,\gcd(x,h)=1$. So by theorem of invariant factors for minimal polynomial, $V$ is the direct sum of invariant subspaces of $T$ and $h(T)$, i.e.
$$V=V_1\oplus V_2$$
where $V_1=\{x:Tx=0\},V_2=\{x:h(T)x=0\}$.

Clearly $V_1=\ker{T}$.

Since $Tx\ne 0$ for any $x\in V_2$ and $x\ne0$, $V_2=\text{Im}{T}$.

Comment: do you have a reference for this standard theorem?

Comment: The Theorem could be known as invariant factors minimal polynomial and can be found on any advanced linear algebra text. Please see Theorem 17 on page 343 on Survey of Modern Algebra by Garrett Birkhoff.